# Alternatives to Django post_save

Tags: django, django-models

a question on Django signals, e.g. post_save:

My understanding is that object updates caused by a `post_save` signal fire an additional call on that object's `post_save`. Taking it a step further, syncing two models via 2 `post_save` signals calls `post_save` on one model's object, which then calls `post_save` on the other model's object, then `post_save` back on the original, at the least. Is there a way to disable the recursion here?

Also, in general, is this actually a pattern that is scalable and endorsed by the Django community? Recently came across [this article](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/) suggesting overriding model save function, but it seems like that approach isn't viewed positively across Django users either. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you share the 2 post_save handlers in your question?

Comment: I'm not aware of any issues overriding model save method and if you do that you can actually pass an extra argument to indicate that it is coming from another overridden save method, breaking the loop. Signals are useful when you don't want to modify the source code of the model (such as a third party library).

Comment: Hm, not sure sharing function code is a viable option, which is why I wanted to ask at a high level (I apologize for this). Obscuring the models themselves using a theoretical not-as-well-defined Airbnb database that has a Traveler model and a Booking model with `first_name` and `last_name` on both. Assuming that, for some reason, you want to enable editing of `first_name` and `last_name` of tentative bookings (completed bookings, i.e. past trips, are unaffected) and synchronize with the Traveler's `first_name` and `last_name`, I've created two `post_save` functions on model to save the other.

Comment: That's good to know @Selcuk. Looking back, the few instances where overriding model save method was discouraged resembled the argument of this site: "Overriding a save() method can be done but is not generally recommended as signals/receivers are designed for that specific case." I suppose an argument against method A simply b/c method B exists is not a strong one.

Comment: @BobbyMoogs do you *want* the other post_save handler to be called when the first handler updates the related model? You can use the update method on a queryset to skip signal handlers `Model.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(foo=bar)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you found this assertion that overidding `Model.save` would be "discouraged" and that "signals where designed for that specific case" but it's just plain non-sense. On the first point, just [refer to the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods):

> There’s another set of model methods that encapsulate a bunch of database behavior **that you’ll want to customize**. In particular **you’ll often want to change the way save() and delete() work**.
>
> You’re free to override these methods (and any other model method) to alter behavior.
>
> **A classic use-case for overriding the built-in methods is if you want something to happen whenever you save an object**.

It couldn't make it clearer that overriding `save()` IS the officially recommended (and plain obvious) thing to do.

Now with regard to signals, here again [the official documentation is quite clear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/):

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps allow **decoupled applications** get notified when actions occur **elsewhere** in the framework.

IOW, signals are meant to help writing well-decoupled (and possibly reusable) apps - NOT to add custom behaviours to your *own* models (which wouldn't make any sense - you own the models, so why use any indirection level when you can just override the model's methods ?).